# Watir: Search table cell by bgcolor tag and get column number

Tags: ruby, watir

Consider the following html as an example. its a scratch sheet I made to practice, but it has a snippet of the real html I am trying to work with.

http://www.carbide-red.com/prog/test_table.html

I am trying to locate a column and the only consistant identifier I can find is the background color (bgcolor).

```
<tr bgcolor="#ffffcc">
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="date" align=center>Equipment</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ccccff" align=center class="date"><font color=black>8/12/12</font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#ccccff" align=center class="date"><font color=black>8/19/12</font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#ccccff" align=center class="date"><font color=black>8/26/12</font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#ccccff" align=center class="date"><font color=black>9/2/12</font></td>
    <td bgcolor="red" align=center class="date"><font color=yellow>9/9/12</font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#ccffcc" align=center class="date"><font color=black>9/16/12</font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#ccffcc" align=center class="date"><font color=black>9/23/12</font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#ccffcc" align=center class="date"><font color=black>9/30/12</font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#ccffcc" align=center class="date"><font color=black>10/7/12</font></td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to find the `<td>` that has bgcolor=red. I would then like to save the column index of that cell, so that I can then use it to select the same column of the following rows.

But I can't seem to find a way to search for the `bgcolor=` tag. And I have not been able to find a way to get Watir to report back the column/row indexs to store in a variable. But if I can find the `bgcolor=` tag then I can search for like "equipment" and then count until I find the correct tag.

I know the html code is not ideal due to there note being any "name" or anything unique identifier, but I can't change that.

I am very new to Ruby & Watir. I tried to manipulate a website in Perl and it was was not going very well, and I discovered Watir and it did exactly what I needed (and suprisingly easy), but now I am trying to understand Ruby as well as the finer semantics.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get text of `<td bgcolor="red">` try this:

```
browser.element(:css => "td[bgcolor=red]").text
```

You should get back `"9/9/12"`. To click the element, replace `text` with `click`.

To put it's index in variable `index` try this:

```
index = nil
browser.tds.each_with_index {|td, i| index = i if td.attribute_value("bgcolor") == "red" or td.attribute_value("bgcolor") == "#ff0000"}
```

`index` variable should be `5`.

Comment: I will also try this as it does not require an additional gem.

Comment: The second line does not print anything to screen. It does not error out, but no additional line is created, like the "if" isn't being satisfied. Also yes, if you could show how to put that into a variable please (just do variablename = code?).

Comment: It looks like IE (watir-classic or watir-webdriver) always returns the hex code for the bgcolor. Try using "#ff0000" instead of "red".

Comment: Yup that worked! `browser.tds.each_with_index {|td, index| puts index if td.attribute_value("bgcolor") == "#ff0000" } `

Comment: How can I set the result of that string to a variable instead of printing to console?

Answer (score 1):

I would use nokogiri if I were you:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML @browser.html
td = doc.at('td[@bgcolor="red"]')
index = td.search('./preceding-sibling::td').length
```

Unless there's tricky javascript on the page you're probably better off with mechanize than watir.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the webpage I'm dealing with uses Javascript which is why I had a very hard time useing Mechanize::Firefox under Perl. Watir worked much more smoothly.

Thank you for your suggestion! It didn't work at first, but it helped me with Google searches and I was able to get a working version.

```ruby
require "watir"
require "nokogiri"

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://www.carbide-red.com/prog/test_table.html"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html) 
td = doc.at('td[@bgcolor="red"]') 
columnindex = td.search('./preceding-sibling::td').length 

puts columnindex
browser.close
```

This returned "5"

**Update:**

For the sake of others who may find this while searching and learning. To use `columnindex` variable to find a specific column within a row use this code:

```ruby
textvariable = browser.td(:text => "A58004").parent.td(:index => "#{columnindex}").text
puts "Textvariable: #{textvariable}"
```

This finds a `<td>` that contains the term "A58004" and then goes to the 5th column (0-5) over and returns the value of that cell. Using the webpage linked in my original question that would be "W=Sa"